# Using the Bing API, how can I achieve the same cylindrical view as the Bing iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

In my iPad app I have to integrate Bing maps and their Bird's Eye view.

I have successfully used the Bing API in my app, but after certain level of zooming it is not giving me the cylindrical view as seen in the Bing app on the App Store.

How can I present this same cylindrical view from Bing maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After too much googling i came to know that....
The Bing Maps Application has some features not available in the development sdk.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the v7 bing maps control in your app?

If so, map sure the map type you've selected is automatic (the MapTypeId property in the map options when you create the map).

Also make sure you're zooming into a location that does have bird's eye view data. For example, I tried Seattle downtown area, and that works fine.

You can try this at http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#CreateMap1

I believe this should apply to the iOS control as well.